# Issue with loading large CSV file into MySql database with mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have a database that I am loading a large csv file into. Until recently the script below worked without any issues, and I have not made any changes to the script itself, however it has suddenly stopped working.

An example of the CSV file is

```
"Offer.ID","Offer.PhoneCost","Offer.TotalCost","Offer.MonthlyCost","Offer.FreeGift","Offer.FreeGiftImage","Offer.FreeGiftCategory","Offer.FullFreeGift","Offer.OfferCashback","Offer.AutoCashback","Offer.Clearance","Offer.OfferMins","Offer.OfferTxts","Offer.OfferRental","Offer.OfferLength","Offer.OfferText","Offer.Link"
"8676820","0.00","165.00","13.75","","","","15.00 Guaranteed Cashback","15.00","1","0","0","0","15.00","0","£15.00 Automatic Cashback","http://www.urmob.co.uk/t/a/psav89/URMOB-xmakex-xmodelx-xtariffx/track.php%253fid=8676820"
```

and the PHP script I'm using is...

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconnect.php';

$dbh = db_connect();
$log = fopen("database-log.txt", "w");
$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 

//start the log
$logstart = "------------------------------------------------\n" . $time . " log start\n------------------------------------------------\n\n";
fwrite($log, $logstart);

//clean the temp table
$query = "TRUNCATE TEMPDATA";
$trunc = mysqli_query($dbh, $query);

if ($trunc) {
    fwrite($log, "TEMPDATA cleared\n");
} else {
    fwrite($log, "TEMPDATA failed\n");
}

//load affiliate window csv
$query = "load data local infile '/home/data.csv' into table rim6jtvnox6vmwxk.TEMPDATA FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS";
$update = mysqli_query($dbh, $query);

fwrite($log, $update);

if ($update) {
    fwrite($log, "TEMPDATA Table updated with CSV\n");
} else {
    fwrite($log, "Failed CSV update - " . mysqli_error($dbh) . "\n");
}

mysqli_close($dbh);

$endtime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
$logend = "\n\n------------------------------------------------\n" . $endtime . " log end\n------------------------------------------------\n";
//end the log
fwrite($log, $logend);
fclose($log);

?>
```

I know that the connection to the database is working without any issues, and can see the database being cleared. But the load script doesn't seem to execute and doesn't give any error from `mysqli_error` either.